# GRASS GIS 7.8 trigometric function of vector attribtue

Tags: python, grass-gis, sql, sqlite, grass.script

I need to calculate the sin and cos of a vector attribute column, but these functions do not appear to be available. In Python I've tried using `v.db.update`:

```
gscript.run_command('v.db.update', map='orientation', column='Z', query_column='COS(AZIMUTH)')
```

but this was unsuccessful. Does anyone have recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that SQLite by default lacks log(), sqrt(), cos(), and other functions.
To overcome this limitation you need an addition to SQLite for this: the "SQLite extended functions".

Please check the v.to.db manual page for it in the section [Updating of columns with on the fly calculation (SQLite extended functions)](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/v.db.update.html#updating-of-columns-with-on-the-fly-calculation-(sqlite-extended-functions)).

It provides two links (for Linux and Windows) explaining how to compile this library/DLL yourself.